# Transformation of Uniform variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, density-function, change-of-variable

I am looking for feedback on my solution to the following problem: A random variable X has a uniform distribution on $(c, 4c)$ with $c > 0$. $Y$ is given by $ \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & x \in (2c,3c) \\
      0 & \text{OW}
\end{array} 
\right.$

Find the distribution of $Y$.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

We have that $S_X = \{ x: f_X(x)\geq 0 \} = (c, 4c) $ and $S_Y = \{y: y=g(x) \text{ for some x in } S_X\} = \{ y: y =g(x) \text{ for } x \in (2c,3c)\}$. Since $f$ is continuous on $S_X$ and $g^{-1}(y) = y$ has a continuous derivative on $S_Y$, we get: $$f_Y(y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy}\right| & y \in (2c,3c) \\
      0 & \text{OW}
\end{array} 
\right. = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{1}{3c} & y \in (2c,3c) \\
      0 & \text{OW}
\end{array} 
\right.$$

Thanks for any help/feedback you may have for me!

Comment: There is no density of $Y$ since $Y$ takes the value $0$ with positive probability. You should look for the distribution function instead.

Comment: If you check your calculation for $f(y)$, you'll see it doesn't integrate to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resulting density is not absolutely continuous. so $f_Y(y)=\frac{2}{3}$ when $Y=0$

the rest is correct but no calculation is needed because in the interval you calculated it is given that $Y=X$

Now your density is good because you have

$$\frac{2}{3}+\int_{2c}^{3c}\frac{1}{3c}dy=1$$

So, concluding, you density is the following

$$f_Y(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{3},  & \text{if $y=0$} \\
\frac{1}{3c},  & \text{if $2c<y<3c$} \\
0, & \text{if OW}
\end{cases}$$

EDIT: graph of the transformation function

as you can see, Y-domain is $\{0\} \cup (2c;3c)$

[image]

Comment: How can we say its $2/3$ when $Y=0$. Is it just because it makes total probability equal to 1? Is pdf defined when $Y=0$

Comment: @ShivTavker:  X is defined in $(c;4c)$ but Y=0 when $x \in (c;2c) \cup (3c;4c)$ , In that interval X has a cumulated probability of $\frac{2}{3}$ so Y has a positive probability mass in $y=0$

Comment: How can we say pdf exists at $Y=0$? I agree PMF is $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @ShivTavker : it is told in the transformation function. Do a graph of this transformation function and you will realize that

Comment: This may be a 'generalized density' but I feel it is misleading to call it a density in the usual sense. The question does not even ask for a density.

Comment: @ShivTavker : I did the graph for you..see my edit in answer

Comment: @tommik Thanks for the edit. But, I still don't understand. For a single point like $y=0$ we usually have a singularity right? Oh wait $f_Y(y)$ is pdf right?

Comment: @ShivTavker : right. It is a mixed random variable; discrete in $y=o$ and continuous in the other interval. If you calculate the CDF you will see a "jump" in $Y=0$

Comment: @tommik Thanks I got it know.